# The response code or the response body, it gives me null

Tags: http, https

I am developing a mobile application in java. And I'm trying to get a json response from the free JSONplaceholder service. I have already tried a hundred ways such as OkHttp, HttpURLConnection and so on. And when I try to get the response code or the response body, it gives me null. Please, help. Perhaps this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fm3zj.png) will help to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Code would help understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting the policy.

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```